# Angular 2 RC.5 & VS 2015: Cannot find name 'module', 'Set', 'Map', 'MapConstructor', 'SetConstructor'

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

The issue that I'm having is in the title. Everything that I've read says that it's a typings issue, but I haven't been able to track it down yet. It's a pretty large project, so I'll only give a few example of my settings:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
"exclude": ["node_modules", "typings"]
}
```

**typings.json**

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160807145350"
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.17",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.3.3"
  }
}
```

Things I have tried:

1. Referencing typings files directly in my app's entrypoint
2. Changing compilerOptions -> target to es6/es2015
3. Uninstalling and reinstalling the typings references in the root
4. Updating the typings.json to the most up-to-date versions
5. installing es6-shim and its typings

Any other suggestions would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: it seems you are using VS 2015, Have you checked [VISUAL STUDIO 2015 QUICKSTART Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html)?

Comment: Yes I followed it exclusively when setting up the project. This is a recent issue (past 2 days) after successfully working on the project for months.

Comment: Not an answer on your question but just sharing my experience. I used visual studio but since I use vscode I never want back for my frontend project. Much faster and better for front-end development

Answer (score 1):

Your `package.json` above has `"typescript":"^1.8.10"`, but if you've updated to `2.0.2` in the last day or two it could be [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10633) with Typescript. If so, downgrading to an earlier version should fix it.

Your error messages look very similar to those reported in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1901) on the angular-cli
 project.

Answer (score 0):

Almost forgot about this question...

I resolved this by removing the nuget packages Typescript.Compiler and Typescript.MsBuild from the project.